# How to use a global variable in gcc inline assembly

Tags: c, linux, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I am trying to use inline assembly like this, for a global variable, but the compiler gives an error by saying undefined reference to **saved_sp**.

```
__asm__ __volatile__ (
        "movq saved_sp, %rsp\n\t" );
```

**saved_sp** is declared as `static long saved_sp` globally (for a file that is). What mistake am I doing here?

Comment: Don't you have to pass it in via the extended asm parameters?

Comment: How? I don't want to use any contraints here.

Comment: Then I don't know. I always do it using constraints.

Comment: You might want to specify your `gcc` version. On my Ubuntu box, `gcc 4.4.4` is happy with your code as-is.

Comment: I suggest you include a short yet complete example that doesn't compile for you.

Comment: How about `movq _saved_sp, %rsp`, note the extra underscore?

Comment: Why don't you just compile your C file into assembly file using the `-S` switch and see how the compiler names the variable?

Answer (score 6):

If it fails with "undefined reference to `saved_sp' " (which is really a *linker* error, not a compiler error) when `saved_sp` is `static`, but works when it is not, then it seems likely that the compiler has decided that `saved_sp` is not used in your source file, and has therefore decided to omit it completely from the compiled code that is passed to the assembler.

The compiler does not understand the assembly code inside the `asm` block; it just pastes it into the assembly code that it generates.  So it does not know that the `asm` block references `saved_sp`, and if nothing else in the C code ever reads from it, it is at liberty to decide that it is completely unused - particularly if you have any optimisation options enabled.

You can tell `gcc` that `saved_sp` is used by something that it can't see, and therefore prevent it from choosing to throw it away, by adding the `used` attribute (see the [documentation of variable attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.4/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html), about half-way down the page), e.g.:

```
static long __attribute__((used)) saved_sp;
```

Here's a fully worked example:

```
$ cat test.c
#ifdef FIXED
static long __attribute__((used)) saved_sp;
#else
static long saved_sp;
#endif

int main(void)
{
  __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "movq saved_sp, %rsp\n\t" );
}

$ gcc -m64 -o test test.c
$ gcc -m64 -O1 -o test test.c
/tmp/ccATLdiQ.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x4): undefined reference to `saved_sp'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
$ gcc -m64 -DFIXED -O1 -o test test.c
$
```

(This is from a 32-bit Debian squeeze system with gcc 4.4.5, which is the closest thing I have to hand; `-m64` may well be unnecessary on your system.)

Answer (score 2):

Preferably you would use input and output parameters:

```
__asm__ __volatile__ ( 
    "movq %0, %%rsp\n\t"
    : : "r"(saved_sp) : "memory"
);
```

Often there can be some variables that are not symbols at all at the assembling stage (for example stack variables, or registers. Also, you'd want to clobber the whole memory, to ensure that no stack variables are kept in register after the `saved_sp` is stored in RSP.

Comment: Local vars whose address doesn't escape the function don't have to respect a memory clobber; the compiler knows no other threads could have a reference to it.  Messing around with RSP, like for a context-switch function, really needs to be done in a hand-written function, not with inline asm, unless you're ok with code that happens to compile to working asm for now.

Answer (score 0):

As I indicated in the comments, the following compiles (and generates the correct machine code) using `gcc 4.4.4` on 64-bit Ubuntu:

```
long saved_sp;

int main() {
  __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "movq saved_sp, %rsp\n\t" );
}
```

Perhaps the issue could be something else entirely (a missing `#include` so that `saved_sp` is actually not defined? **edit**: now that you say it's `static`, I guess that's not very likely.)

Comment: Atcually I used static long saved_sp. If I remove static, yes it works fine, but why is that so? Why the compiler doesnt like the static here?

Comment: @MetallicPriest: I can't seem to reproduce this, with or without `static`.

Comment: global variables should be addressed like `saved_sp(%rip)`, not with 32-bit absolute addressing modes.  Also, this is missing a `"memory"` clobber or a `"m"` source operand to tell the compiler the global is read here.  (In this case Antti is right that a `"memory"` clobber is necessary because we're modifying RSP itself, although local vars whose address doesn't escape the function don't have to respect a memory clobber.)